# Executing Windows administrative shell commands on Windows using Python

Tags: windows-7, python, batch-file, runas

I have a batch script using Windows shell commands to perform several administrative actions.
The script is running great on Windows 7 but when i try launching it from Python 2.6 nothing happens:

```
import os
a = os.popen("somebatchfile.bat")
```

I assume that this is because the bat file uses several commands that require an administrative privileges but i don't want to prompt to a password using `runas.exe` or embedding the password within the code.

Is there any way to make UAC prompt for user approval or something?

Comment: Are you running Python with elevated privileges?

Comment: Yes, this also occurs when i'm running Python with elevated privileges while under command line as administrator...

Answer (score 1):

Relevent?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script